# GCM notifications on Android ICS not working

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working with a samsung s3 with android 4.3 and an LG dual with android 4.0.4 (just updated from 2.3)
If I test my app on the samsung it works, I receive the notification (GCM) and it's all ok, but if I test it on the LG with android ICS, the app works but I don't receive notification.

I use this class for receive the notification

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Any idea?
thanks!

UPDATE

this is the manifest (I omitted all the activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.test.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".service.GcmIntentService" />
        <service android:name=".service.UpdateOptionService" />
        <service android:name=".service.UpdateUserService" />


    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you include your manifest in the question?

Comment: Have you checked whether LG device got registered and have a GCM Id

Comment: Yes the LG device is correctly registered in my database with a GCM id

Answer (score 1):

Based on your manifest, your intent service class is not in the same package as the main package of your app.

The app's package is `com.example.test` and the service package is `com.example.test.service`.

Therefore this code would look for the intent service class in the wrong package :

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                                       GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

Try to change it to :

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(GcmIntentService.class.getPackage().getName(),
                                       GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

Comment: I tried to change that row, but it still not working...if I try to send a notification from samsung (4.3) to Lg(4.0) doesn't work, instead from lg to samsung it's ok.